# Generic path issue

Tags: java, file, path

[Assume this is my file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSjX4.png)

```
 public static ArrayList<String[]> loopCSV() throws DBAppException {
    try {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Metadata/Metadata.csv"));
        ArrayList<String[]> TablesName = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator
            String[] r = line.split(",");
            TablesName.add(r);
        }
        return TablesName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DBAppException("can not read the csv file");
    }
}
```

the above method Loop on a csv file within my project solution and do whatever it it does.
I get exception regarding the file path  , however when I add the absolute path from my computer it runs normally
I want the path to be as generic as possible, so it runs everywhere.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Metadata\Metadata.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The execution directory when the application is running maybe a completely different directory from the source path. Don't assume it is in the source path. Always pass the absolute directory to open the file. Unless it is a resource inside the application then you could use [ClassLoader.getResource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).

Comment: yes, it will act as a database containing some info that I will retrieve multiple times from the file. so what should I do in this case?

Comment: If it's data that is as much part of your application as your class files are, this `MyClassWeAreIn.class.getResource("/images/open_icon.png")` for example. `getResourceAsStream`, if you need the data itself, just `getResource` if passing it to anything that takes a `URL`.